# weka .net ikvm -> why loading a csv file is so slow?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, weka, ikvm

I followed the tutorial to use weka from .net
http://weka.wikispaces.com/IKVM+with+Weka+tutorial
Problem:  the weka c# api takes way too much time to load a simple csv file, it takes more than 30 sec for a small file while this same file is loaded in 1 sec by the weka explorer, any idea?

C# sample code:

```
string filename = "weka_file.csv";
// weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource source = new weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource(filename); // doesn't seem to work for csv files
// weka.core.Instances instsOrg = source.getDataSet();
weka.core.converters.CSVLoader csvLoader = new weka.core.converters.CSVLoader();
csvLoader.setSource(new java.io.File(filename));
weka.core.Instances instsOrg = csvLoader.getDataSet(); // this takes 30 secondes for a particular csv file I have and it take only 1 sec to load it in with the weka explorer...
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you running this with F5 in Visual Studio by any chance? In that case you are running inside the debugger and the .NET debugger is horrible with exception performance. Try running with Ctrl-F5 (without debugger).

Answer (score 0):

If that's too much, wait 'till you try to get graphs out of weka. Or rather try to. I recently completed a c# project using weka (j48 algorithm) and since we run weka.jar through ikvm even a 5mb .arff file classification takes too long. So to sum up, your code is ok, but the problem is using weka throught ikvm.

Try to create a seperate thread and just use weka in the background while the application does something else. For graphs, the only option is a seperate java application.